# number and string manipulation in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I wrote a little bash script (my first) that does the following:

```
sed -e 's/Alpha=0/Alpha=x/' -e 's/Beta=0/Beta=y/' <file.pov >tmpfile.pov
povray Width=480 Height=360 +Itmpfile.pov +Ofile_x_y.png
```

everything works as intented but now I would like to pack these two lines in a loop for x=0:30:180 and y=0:30:90 (edit: I mean all possible combinations of x in {0,30,60,90,120,180} and y in {0,30,60,90}).

So for example for x=60 and y=30 the code should behave like this:

```
sed -e 's/Alpha=0/Alpha=60/' -e 's/Beta=0/Beta=30/' <file.pov >tmpfile.pov
povray Width=480 Height=360 +Itmpfile.pov +Ofile_60_30.png
```

I am aware, it should not be too hard, but for some reason, I just couldnt work it out by myself.

Sorry to bother you with my newbie questions!

Comment: you probably meant `'s/Alpha=0/Alpha=x/'`

Comment: Edit your question to show the full set of expected output given those x and y values as it's not clear if you want the output to include all possible combinations of both or if they should be one-to-one matched, nor is it clear even what you mean by `x=0:30:180` and `and y=0:30:90`. Are you starting at zero and incrementing both by 30 but stopping at 180 for x and 90 for y or something else and how do the values relate to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use seq with for loops:

```
for x in `seq 0 30 180`
do for y in `seq 0 30 90`
do sed -e 's/Alpha=0/Alpha='$x'/' -e 's/Beta=0/Beta='$y'/' <file.pov >tmpfile.pov
    fn="file_${x}_${y}.png"
    povray Width=480 Height=360 +Itmpfile.pov +O${fn}
done done
```

`seq` is a great tool even if you don't need the numbers

```
for i in `seq 10`
do call_me_ten_times
done
```

Comment: I think there was a problem with the ${fn} using `$x_$y`. It tries to read `$x_` so I changed that to `${x}_${y}`. I tried the sed with a simple file containing `Alpha=0` and `Beta=0`. But I forgot the first `-e`. Sorry. Now it works.

Comment: I use shells without these number features `{0..30..180}`. So I learned to like seq.

Comment: It doesn't matter for the example, but the for loop runs about 2 times faster than a read for big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

here is a tricky bash hack, but it helps to reduce two nested for loop into a single while loop:

```
while read x y; do
    sed -e 's/Alpha=0/Alpha='"$x"'/' -e 's/Beta=0/Beta='"$y"'/' <file.pov >"tmpfile${x}_$y.pov"
done < <(echo {0..180..30}' '{0..90..30} | tr ' ' '\n' | paste - -)
```

the process substitution at last generates all combinations of the range you specified.

one remaining problem should be the output file name. since you are overwriting the file every time. i think it would be better if you make the filename changes as it goes. perhaps in my way.

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm! i dont use different output files because i clean them up after all the rendering is done anyways.